# Angular: is there a way to display raw (original/not compiled) code in a template

Tags: angular, syntax-highlighting, string-interpolation, highlightjs

In an Angular 8 application, I need to show the original html code without its evaluation (like code snippet).

E.g.

```
<div #sample>
    {{'standard-button' | translate}}
    <ng-container *ngIf="!clicked">
        {{'not' | translate}}
    </ng-container>
    {{'clicked' | translate}}
</div>
```

There is a way to get exactly the below html?
I'm using highlightJS but unfortunately it evaluates interpolations `{{}}`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Pinturikkio, welcome to stack overflow! Coud you include in your question an example of the data you are passing into the template and what you expect the output to look like for easier clarification?

Comment: Hi @chrismclarke, I would simply like to have the template in action on the left and the code on the right (without having to rewrite it as a string)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense thanks. I think ngNonBindable should work as described in the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ngNonBindable directive that tells Angular not to compile or bind the contents of the current DOM element.

```
<div ngNonBindable  #sample>
  {{'standard-button' | translate}}
  <ng-container *ngIf="!clicked">
    {{'not' | translate}}
  </ng-container>
  {{'clicked' | translate}}
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to add a link to the docs but there aren't any!
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19497
But nice find :D

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a string variable

```
    private htmlTemplate: string = "<div #sample>
    {{'standard-button' | translate}}
    <ng-container *ngIf='!clicked'>
        {{'not' | translate}}
    </ng-container>
    {{'clicked' | translate}}
</div>"
```

and use it in the template like:

`<div>{{htmlTemplate}}</div>`

Comment: Yes I know, but this isn't the way I want to go. I need something automatized.. I really have a lot of code